# How ignore cheerio from turn attributes to lowercase?

Tags: javascript, cheerio

How to tell cheerio NOT to change the attributes to lowercase?

Currently, `cheerio` turns `fooBar` into `foobar`. how to NOT do it?

[codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-grothendieck-gqpum?file=/src/index.js:0-253)

```
const cheerio = require("cheerio");

const html = `
  <div>
   <h4></h4>
   <img src="">
   <input>
   <p fooBar></p>
  
  </div>

`;

const $ = cheerio.load(html);

const output = $.html();

console.log({ output });
```

I try to add `lowerCaseAttributeNames` according to [answer in github](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio/issues/74) but this not help:

```
const $ = cheerio.load(html, { lowerCaseAttributeNames: false });
```

The results:

```
<html><head></head><body><div>
   <h4></h4>
   <img src>
   <input>
   <p foobar></p> <------------------foobar. expected: fooBar
  
  </div>

</body></html>
```

I try with `xmlMode`, but it creates closing problem:

```
 <div>
   <h4/>
   <img src="">
   <input>
   <p fooBar=""/>
  
  </input></img></div>
```

**UPADTE**

I searched the `lowerCaseAttributeNames` in Github, but it [only exist in the types](https://github.com/search?q=org%3Acheeriojs+lowerCaseAttributeNames&type=code), not sure it have impact on the code :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After I did some digging into `cheerio` source code and many other libraries, I understand you can use `cheerio` to get what you want.

first, you should load the content by `xmlMode:true` and use `xmlMode:false` when you call to `html()`:

```
const $ = cheerio.load(html, { xmlMode: true });
const output = $.html({ xmlMode: false });
```

The full code is also on [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-satoshi-zch05?file=/src/index.js)

```
const cheerio = require("cheerio");

console.clear();

const html = `
  <div>
   <h4></h4>
   <img src="">
   <input>
   <p fooBar></p>
  
  </div>

`;

const $ = cheerio.load(html, { xmlMode: true, lowerCaseAttributeNames: false });

const output = $.html({ xmlMode: false });

console.log({ output });

/*
<div>
   <h4></h4>
   <img src>
   <input>
   <p fooBar></p>
  
  </div>
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

Cheerio is using parser5 by default and the `lowerCaseAttributeName` is a htmlparser2 attribute.

You could try to load the htmlparser2 at the start as indicated in their [github](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio#loading) page:

```
// Usage as of htmlparser2 version 3:
const htmlparser2 = require('htmlparser2');
const dom = htmlparser2.parseDOM(document, options);

const $ = cheerio.load(dom);
```