# Convert ast back to template string in Vue

Tags: vue.js, abstract-syntax-tree

I am using vue-template-compiler to change attribs in specific div, after updating I want to convert the ast's back to template string. How can I do it?

I want something like dom-serializer for vue.
https://github.com/cheeriojs/dom-serializer#readme

```
const vtc = require('vue-template-compiler')

function parseVueComponent() {
    const template = `
    <template>
        <div id="id_1" v-if="true">test</div>
        <div>test2</div>
    </template>
    <script>
    const a = 1
    <script>
    `
    const compiled = vtc.compile(template)
    compiled.ast.children.forEach(v => {
        if(v.tag === 'div') {
            v.attrsMap['v-if'] = false
        }
        console.log({ v :v })
    })
    // how to convert ast back to template string
}

parseVueComponent()
```

[image]

Comment: Consider explaining your case, could be XY problem. I doubt it's possible as this would be useless functionality for the purpose this package serves

Comment: But what's the purpose? If you intend to render the component afterwards then you may not need that. As said, could be XY problem.

Comment: In my code there are around 200 vue files and I want to add v-if conditions on some div tag in these 200 files. I am able to add the v-if attribute based on my requirement. Now I want the AST to be converted back to the string and to be written to the vue file. @EstusFlask

Comment: Vue template compile may not be the correct library i am looking into, is there any other library that fulfils my requirement

Comment: I see, so it's an utility and isn't supposed to run at runtime. With vue-template-compiler, you'll have to write this part yourself indeed. I'm unaware of such lib but for this purpose I'd probably go with general purpose html parser that has an option for case sensitivity (in case project style is sensitive), since that's what vue templates actually are, as for cheerio, something like that https://stackoverflow.com/a/65359861/3731501. But for such narrow task  a regex could work too, you can do a pass with a compiler afterwards to make sure the syntax wasn't messed up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just came across this question and I find it very valid. What you're trying to do is sometimes aspect-oriented programming. Based on some rules you'd like to add some functionality and have it implemented as a general concept.

In my case I'd like to parse the templates and replace code like `<something acl="authenticated"...>` to `<something v-if="authenticated"...>` and then to extend the `script` section (or even add one if it doesn't exist) to define what `authenticated` means. In my case, it'll be an import from a specific module, but it can be anything.

In Java, there is such a tool to do it. It's called AOP, so aspect-oriented programming, and runs during compilation. The advantage of AOP in Java is that it works directly against the AST.

To accomplish your goal you'll need to manually serialize the updated AST back to string as there is no `stringify` for that. I might create an publish a package that does it but for now it is all on you.

Edit 15.02.2024:

Check out the [vue-ast-serializer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@padcom/vue-ast-serializer) package. It's way not complete, but for the projects I have it was able to serialize the AST *good enough*. If there's something that you'll be missing please don't hesitate to open a Github issue and/or submit a PR. Thanks!

Edit 16.02.2024:

I've been working on an ACL/feature flag transformer so that I can manage my access rights and feature flags from a central location. As a result, I created [vite-plugin-vue-sfc-transform](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@padcom/vite-plugin-vue-sfc-transform). It accepts a `transformer` function that gets the current filename and a list of sections.
I also noticed that using the original AST provided by Vue's SFC compiler is ugly because they don't store text nodes. It's better to use something like [node-html-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-html-parser) which also makes modifications super easy as it allows you to navigate the content of the `<template>` as though it would be in the browser. Very convenient indeed.

Comment: Thanks @matthias, vue-ast-serializer is the one I was looking for.